# SyntaxError: Cannot find name 'setImmediate'

Tags: node.js, typescript

In my .netcore app I upgraded my Typescript version from `2.4.1` to `3.2.4` and now I am receiving the error `Cannot find name 'setImmediate'` at compile time. The implementation I have below is basically straight from the Microsoft [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2) on pre-rendering.

```
export default createServerRenderer(params => {
    const providers = [
        { provide: INITIAL_CONFIG, useValue: { document: '<app></app>', url: params.url } },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },
    ];

    return platformDynamicServer(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(moduleRef => {
        const appRef: ApplicationRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
        const state = moduleRef.injector.get(PlatformState);
        const zone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);

        return new Promise<RenderResult>((resolve, reject) => {
            zone.onError.subscribe((errorInfo: any) => reject(errorInfo));
            appRef.isStable.pipe(first(isStable => isStable)).subscribe(() => {

                setImmediate(() => { // <!-- error here
                    resolve({
                        html: state.renderToString(),
                        globals: {

                        }
                    });
                    moduleRef.destroy();
                });

            });
        });
    });
});
```

I saw that there [was a bug raised for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/issues/502), however it is marked as resolved and merged. I also tried installing the `setImmediate` package and importing that, however that didn't work either. Anyone know how to resolve this ?

Comment: What does this have to do with .NET Core? [`setImmediate` is a Node.js thing](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args), not a browser thing, [except in a very few browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=setimmediate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Non webpack:**

Installing `npm install --save-dev @types/node` and then importing `import '@types/node';` at the start of the file resolved this issue for me.

---

**Webpack:**

If you are using webpack then this will not work. Instead `npm install --save-dev @types/node node` then you will have to:

Go into your `.tsconfig` and add `'node'`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "types": [..., "node" ],
      ...
   }
}
```

do not `import '@types/node';` this is for the reasons stated [here](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/244):

> `@types` packages are stored in the `@types` directory but they must never be manually imported. Rather, you need to import the dependency they correspond to from where that dependency is installed. `@types` packages provide the type declarations for dependencies that do not otherwise provide them.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the solution using webpack, and I noticed that there is no need to npm install node, just install @types/node (and follow the rest of the instructions of course) and it will work perfectly :)